# Laying out multiple images in a figure

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I've got the following figure I want to reproduce in my thesis (blurred because of licensing):

[image: figure to reproduce: single big image on the left block, the right block is divided into 2x2 images]

My MWE is this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[tb]
        \centering

        \caption{asd}
        \label{}

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c c }
            \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a} & {\begin{tabularx}{.45\linewidth}{ c c }
                    \includegraphics[width=.225\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b} & \includegraphics[width=.225\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c} \\
                    \includegraphics[width=.225\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b} & \includegraphics[width=.225\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c} \\
                \end{tabularx}} \\
        \end{tabularx}

    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which results in an ugly layout, I don't know exactly why:

[image: result of MWE]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Organizing image in table with measurement of smaller image height:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\newsavebox\image

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[tb]
    \centering
\caption{asd}
\label{fig:myimportantfigure}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
    \setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio}
    \sbox\image{\includegraphics[width=0.225\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-a}}
\begin{tabular}{c p{0.225\linewidth}p{0.225\linewidth}}
\multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[height=\dimexpr2\ht\image+2\dp\image+2pt,valign=t]{example-image-duck}}
    & \usebox\image & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-b} \\
    \addlinespace[2pt]
    & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-b} 
\end{tabular}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hats off to the savebox trick. Just a tiny thing, luatex complains of an overfull `\vbox` in the main picture, can it be solved?

Comment: @amyspark, huh, LuaTeX :-(, I'm not familiar with it. With my understanding it, it should not complain. About this is the best to ask new question (tagged with LuaTeX). Anyway, if complains are warnings, then this is not so critical :-)

Answer (score 3):

With `minipage`s and `valign=t` from the `adjustbox` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
\caption{asd}
\label{label}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-a}
     \end{minipage}%
     \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-b}\hfill
         \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-c}
         \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-b}\hfill
         \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-c}
     \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `tabularx`, you have to use at least one `X` column, and actually here  3 X columns. I gave the code to have the  `X` columns width different widths in the ratio `2:1:1`. Other than that, you need to use `\multirow`. The vertical adjustment is done by the number of equivalent rows it is supposed to be spanning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption, multirow}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[tb]
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
        \caption{asd}
        \label{}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\hsize=1.5\hsize\centering}X *{2}{>{\hsize=0.75\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X} @{}}
          & \includegraphics[width=0.225\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b} & \includegraphics[width=0.225\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c} \tabularnewline
           \multirow{-8.22}{=}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}} & \includegraphics[width=0.225\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b} & \includegraphics[width=0.225\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]